# How much do quantum fluctuations affect our lives?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, everyday-life, determinism, randomness

In other words, how deterministic is our daily lives given the probabilistic attributes of quantum mechanics? How much does the randomness of quantum mechanics affect our thoughts and our actions?

To take a specific example, let’s say I am going to take a 10-minute drive. Given as much information as possible of the start of the system, how certain could you be of the exact amount of time that drive would take with 99% percent certainty? Within a second, a millisecond, microsecond, etc.?

Comment: There is currently no accepted theory of quantum fluctuations in spacetime itself, and no measurements have ever shown any quantum effects on either space or time. Quantum mechanics and the quantum field theories in the Standard Model are about particles and their interactions. Eventually we may have an accepted theory of quantum gravity and quantum spacetime but at the moment all of them are speculative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at the level of everyday life, the less fundamental uncertainty of our measuring devices, using rulers and clocks, plays a much larger role. So much so that any quantum fluctuations would go unnoticed.

**Edit** My answer only applies to things like position and time, you know, basic everyday measurements. Although the question indicated something along those lines, @GSmith's answer better reflects how quantum fluctuations can be seen and affect our lives. For another example, crystals like ruby would not have their brilliant color were it not for the periodic structure of the atoms enhancing the quantum effects.

Answer (score 6):

The probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics can have dramatic consequences in your daily life.

For example, most cancers are caused by a single mutant cell. Usually multiple mutations are required. Various kinds of radiation (ultraviolet light, x-rays, cosmic rays, alpha and beta particles from natural background radioactivity, solar neutrinos, etc.) can cause the DNA in cells to mutate. The interaction of the radiation with the electrons and nuclei in the cell’s atoms is a quantum-mechanical process.

Consider a cosmic gamma photon passing through a particular cell. The interaction has various possible outcomes, each with a particular quantum-mechanical probability. Most likely, it passes through without doing any damage, or interacts harmlessly with a non- critical part of the cell. But there are small probabilities that it changes the chemical structure of some DNA base, or breaks the sugar-phosphate backbone of the DNA, or breaks the hydrogen bond connecting two base pairs. If one of these outcomes produces a critical mutation, and your body is unable to repair it, you may develop a cancer that kills you.

Answer (score -4):

I'm guessing that it is the uncertainties associated with the atomic interactions in the brain that make free will possible.